# Unit-testing an angular service with Karma/Jasmine/JSPM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, jspm, angular-mock

I'm writing a unit test with for my application written in Angular 1 and JSPM with Karma and Jasmine.

Here is my Karma config (jspm section) :

```js
jspm: {
    meta: {
        'jspm_packages/github/angular/angular.js': {
            format: 'global',
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        'jspm_packages/github/angular/angular-mocks.js': {
            format: 'global',
            deps:   'angular'
        }
    },
    loadFiles: [
        'test/**/*.js'
    ],
    serveFiles: [
        'app/**/*.js'
    ]
},
```

To begin, I want to test a custom angular service :

```js
// imports

class Game {

    constructor($rootScope, $http, $timeout, $translate, $location) {

        // ...

        this.$rootScope.game = this;

    }

}
```

Here is my test file :

```js
import { module, inject } from 'angular-mocks';

describe('this is a test', function () {

    beforeEach(module('module-name'));

    var game;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_game_) {
        game = new _game_;
    }));

    it('should be defined', function () {
        expect(game).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

The main problem is I keep having this error. The `inject` function from angular-mocks doesn't seem to work because, I have my variable `game` not defined, but it should be.

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0) should be defined FAILED
    forEach
    loadModules
    createInjector
    workFn
    {path}/node_modules/karma-jspm/src/adapter.js:61:24
    tryCatchReject@D:/{path}/jspm_packages/system-polyfills.src.js:1188:34
    runContinuation1@D:/{path}/jspm_packages/system-polyfills.src.js:1147:18
    when@D:/{path}/jspm_packages/system-polyfills.src.js:935:20
    run@D:/{path}/jspm_packages/system-polyfills.src.js:826:17
    _drain@D:/{path}/jspm_packages/system-polyfills.src.js:102:22
    drain@D:/{path}/jspm_packages/system-polyfills.src.js:67:15
    Expected undefined to be defined.
    D:/{path}/node_modules/karma-jspm/src/adapter.js:61:24
    tryCatchReject@D:/{path}/jspm_packages/system-polyfills.src.js:1188:34
    runContinuation1@D:/{path}/jspm_packages/system-polyfills.src.js:1147:18
    when@D:/{path}/jspm_packages/system-polyfills.src.js:935:20
    run@D:/{path}/jspm_packages/system-polyfills.src.js:826:17
    _drain@D:/{path}/jspm_packages/system-polyfills.src.js:102:22
    drain@D:/{path}/jspm_packages/system-polyfills.src.js:67:15
```

So, I can't figure out why it doesn't work. Any clue?

Comment: Any solution for this? I am also facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

maybe too late by now, but try it without the new keyword:

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_game_) {
    game = _game_;
}));
```